# Jax Implementation of function similar to Torch's 'Scatter'

Tags: python, graph, deep-learning, pytorch, jax

For graph learning purposes, I am trying to implement a global sum batching function, that takes as inputs batched graph representations 'x' of size (n x d) and a corresponding vector of batches (n x 1). I then want to compute the sum over all graph representations for each batch. Here is a graphical representation: [torch's scatter function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f1pX.png)

This is my current attempt:

```
def global_sum_pool(x, batch):
    graph_reps = []
    i = 0
    n = jnp.max(batch)
    while True:
        ind = jnp.where(batch == i, True, False).reshape(-1, 1)
        ind = jnp.tile(ind, x.shape[1])
        x_ind = jnp.where(ind == True, x, 0.0)
        graph_reps.append(jnp.sum(x_ind, axis=0))
        if i == n:
            break
        i += 1
    return jnp.array(graph_reps)
```

I get the following exception on the line `if i == n`:

```
jax.errors.TracerBoolConversionError: Attempted boolean conversion of traced array with shape bool[]..
The error occurred while tracing the function make_step at /venvs/jax_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/equinox/_jit.py:37 for jit.
```

I understand this is due to the fact that at compile time, Jax does not a priori know the max value of the 'batch' array and hence cannot allocate memory. Does anyone know a workaround or different implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than implementing this via a `for` loop, you should use JAX's built-in [`scatter`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scatter.html) operator. The most convenient interface for this is the [`Array.at`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.ndarray.at.html) syntax. If I understand your goal correctly, it might look something like this:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
num_batches = 4
n = 10
d = 3
x = np.random.randn(n, d)
ind = np.random.randint(low=0, high=num_batches, size=(n,))

#Compute the result with jax.lax.scatter
result = jnp.zeros((num_batches, d)).at[ind].add(x)
print(result.shape)
# (4, 3)
```